# Output of shell commands is going beyond available screen space

Tags: external-command

When Im writing shell scripts I often want to run/check a block of code, by

- <kbd>V</kbd> highlight block
- then `:'<,'>w !bash`

vim will then execute highlighted block and display output at the bottom of vim's display - displacing the current buffer with the shell output.
The problem is sometimes the output goes beyond the top of the screen and when in that state, no key commands to navigate the text seem available - i.e. any key just returns back to the buffer.

Ive tried piping into less, e.g. `:'<,'>w !bash | less`, this actually  crashed my vim instance!

How can I display the output in a useful way, e.g.

- move around the existing output, kind of like less (ideal)
- sending large output to a new buffer (good)
- sending output into a new file (ok, if no better options)

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "It crashed my instance"? Because I just tried to execute a loop echoing 200 lines with `:'<,'>w !bash | less` and it seems to work perfectly on a terminal vim 7.4 on Debian. I can move up and down the lines with `j` and `k` and go back to the buffer with `q`.

Comment: I cant remember the shell command I ran but it vim showed a bunch of errors then locked up vim. after that I also read that the | character has a different meaning on vims command prompt, so after that I didnt risk trying piping into less. will give it another go though

Comment: Indeed in vim command line `|` can be used to separate commands, so you can give multiple commands in one. But as you use `!` you're calling external shell command so in your example it works as a classical shell pipe. Give us an update and more details when you'll have reproduced you the crashing with the pipe :-)

Comment: @statox thanks, I tried piping into less again, and it worked once. However  I just tried executing a long list of echo statements - I thought executing interactive commands like `read` would cause problems so I avoided that. Im getting `E388: Couldn't find definition`. again vim unresponsive - so Ive had to kill the shell process

Comment: `E388` indicates that the definition of a function or of a variable can't be found ([`:h E388`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tagsrch.html#E388)) so are you sure your script is working? Did you tried to execute it directly from your shell (not in vim)?

Comment: ah, yes the script is working when invoked from a bash command prompt. Also, I tried simply executing a block of echo statements and piping into less - to eliminate the possibility it could be something in the shell script itself. again its crashing. this time it executes shell commands and correctly loads less with content, then when I `q` out of less. I get an unresponsive vim. this time the `E388` only came up after I started trying commands to regain control over vim , in this case `ctrl-c`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29386/discussion-between-statox-and-user4668401).

Comment: Is the crash reproducible? What Vim version?

Comment: VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan  2 2014 19:39:32)
Included patches: 1-52 . OS Ubuntu 14.04.  Setup is as per my question. Command is:  `:'<,'>w !bash | less`

Comment: the shell commands I was trying to execute was simple a block of echo comands ,e,g `echo  " * Updating packages" ` about 12 lines of similar echo statements

Comment: So not reproducible. In case it happens again, please report back to vim-dev ml

Comment: ok, it pretty much seems to happen everytime. the steps to reproduce are simply what I posted. My vim / tmux / bash / less setup and config is probably harder to reproduce. If I can provide a worthwhile bug report, I will, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Clam](https://github.com/sjl/clam.vim) is very useful for that kind of scenario:

1. select a bunch of lines,
2. do `:'<,'>Clam bash`
3. get the result in a vertical Vim window,
4. go back to your script, edit it, run it again in the same vertical window.